# Show selected ListView item in Content presenter

Tags: xaml, listview, mvvm, win-universal-app, datatemplate

I am trying to display an selected listview item in a ContentPresenter.

The ListView is populated from the Player**s**ViewModel. The items presenting a PlayerViewModel.

Now I want to display the selected PlayerViewModel outside the ListView in an ContentPresenter. In the design view only the Content binded type is shown. Like: *PlayersViewModel.CurrentPlayer*.

How can I make the ContentPresenter work the same way as the ListView.ItemTemplate?

Thanks in advance.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind PlayersViewModel.Players}" SelectedIndex="{x:Bind PlayersViewModel.Index}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">            
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:PlayerViewModel">
                <Viewbox>
                    <StackPanel BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Score, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Viewbox>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="{x:Bind PlayersViewModel.CurrentPlayer}">
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplateCurrentPlayer"  x:DataType="viewModels:PlayerViewModel">
                <StackPanel BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Score, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>            
    </ContentPresenter>
```

Comment: Why you have to display in ContentPresenter? Any reason?

Comment: Do you have CurrentPlayer property in PlayersViewModel? Are you getting any binding exception when you run?

Comment: Yes CurrentPlayer property is in PlayersViewModel. No binding exception uccurs. I want to show more detailed information of the selected item in the ContentPresenter. If I can do that with an different control thats ok.

Comment: I don't know why are you using ContentPresenter. You can achieve your result using just stackpanel which is inside of your ContentPresenter

Comment: Or you can use ListView Footer Template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<UserControl x:Class="App1.MyUserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="using:App1"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="400">

  <UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:PlayerViewModel"
                  x:Key="PlayerTemplate">
      <Viewbox>
        <StackPanel BorderBrush="Black"
                    BorderThickness="1">
          <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
          <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Score, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Viewbox>
    </DataTemplate>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind PlayersViewModel.Players}"
              SelectedIndex="{x:Bind PlayersViewModel.Index}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PlayerTemplate}" />

    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                    Content="{x:Bind PlayersViewModel.CurrentPlayer}"
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PlayerTemplate}" />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListView Footer Template to show detailed information of selected item

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind PlayersViewModel.Players}" SelectedIndex="{x:Bind PlayersViewModel.Index}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">            
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:PlayerViewModel">
                <Viewbox>
                    <StackPanel BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Score, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Viewbox>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
<ListView.FooterTemplate>

      <DataTemplatex:DataType="viewModels:PlayerViewModel">
            <StackPanel BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind PlayersViewModel.CurrentPlayer.Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind PlayersViewModel.CurrentPlayer.Score, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.FooterTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Or other way is you can use just Stackpanel

```
   <StackPanel BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind PlayersViewModel.CurrentPlayer.Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind PlayersViewModel.CurrentPlayer.Score, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
```

Hope this works..